# How can I get google proxy servers to ignore parts of my site?

Tags: .htaccess, proxy, drupal-7, robots.txt, access-denied

I am using drupal and in my watchdog log entries, I have the following IP addresses trying to access parts of my site that they shouldn't be. They get logged as "access denied". Normally, I would just block these IP addresses, but after looking them up, I found that they are google proxies. The hostnames look like this google-proxy-66-249-83-213.google.com.I have the parts of my site disallowed in my robots.txt file. When I go to google webmaster tools and test the robots.txt file it confirms that it cannot access those urls.

Offending IPs:

```
66.249.83.213
66.249.88.227
66.249.88.223
66.249.88.225
66.249.83.207
```

What can I do to stop them from trying to access those parts without restricting them completely? Is there something I can put in my htaccess file or something?  Anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a robots.txt file to prevent crawlers from accessing specific areas of your site.

Here's a sample of how you can configure it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /~joe/
```

You can find more details [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) for instance.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue, where every day, a different google-proxy domain is accessing my web service. Somehow, the link got indexed.

The bad news is that I see no log of it trying to access robots.txt at all - so, adding anything in there won't help.

The only way I found to get rid of this is to block it in the firewall. I added an inbound rule to block 66.249.64.0/19 , which covers the IP range of all google-proxy domains (net range 66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255)